# how to create a multiple row activity

Tags: android, listview

how do i create a multiple row app with the same data for each row. This is how all the rows are to look like. it contains three text views and two spinners. this app is to help calculate the gpa of a student for one semester.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.mbedobe.android.samplegpacalculator.app.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="C1"
    android:id="@+id/course_textView"/>



<Spinner
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/course_textView"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/course_textView"
    android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="23dp" />

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinner2"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="23dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="0"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spinner2"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/spinner2"
    android:id="@+id/gradePoints"
    android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="23dp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="0"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/gradePoints"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/gradePoints"
    android:id="@+id/gradeValue"
    android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="23dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Look up a ListView or a RecyclerView.

Comment: You are looking for [`ListView`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) with custom list item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should think about using a [ListView with BaseAdapter](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-a-BaseAdapter-with-ListView).

Comment: after using the list view with base adapter, I got a blank screen

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to use [RecycleView](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use a [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) with a [custom adapter](https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-recyclerview). The layout above will be the row layout for each row in this case.

Use the links above to understand how you can create your own Custom RecyclerView Adapters with Custom Layouts.

**EDIT:**

Ok, I'll give you the basics here. There are three major things you need for a custom RecyclerView.

They are:

1. List of Objects (your data)
2. A custom layout for each row
3. An Adapter that will transform your data onto the above layout.

Now, let's take an example and try and explain this.

You must have seen popular apps like Gmail, WhatsApp, etc.
When you open these apps, you see a list of Emails/Chats etc.
One thing to notice is that the layout for each row is same, even though the content inside them is different.

This tells us 2 things: first that the data must be a list of the same kind of objects, and secondly that the layout of each row is the same. So, to create such a listView or RecyclerView, we shouldn't need to create as many layouts as there are rows. One layout can be reused for each row.

So, two of our three needs are understood. The final item required is the Adapter. The adapter is what takes your List and converts each item from the list into a row on your RecyclerView. These rows are automatically created by the Adapter as the user scrolls through the list, and removed when the user can no longer see those rows.

If you want code for this, let me know. I'll upload code explaining this. But I would recommend you try it out on your own. It's not that hard.

Comment: i have looked at those and a few other tutorials but i am not really understanding what is happening. can you help?

Comment: i have looked at the links you gave but the problem is i am not understanding how to go about it. i even looked up a few tutorials, how do i do it using my layout?

Comment: what list of objects are you referring to?

Comment: is it possible to send you my code for you to look at? the adapter samples I have looked at do not relate to my layout

Comment: Sure.. you can share it on email or on git.. rachitgoy@gmail.com

Comment: I sent you a mail yesterday,hope you have received it.

Answer (score 0):

Either use ListView, recyclerView or dynamically add the items in scrollview.

Use of ListView or RecyclerView will be the best approach for you.

I'll give you the last option that should be worked from java only if you are with good knowledged in java. ( only the steps not complete code)

```
1) your xml file should contain scroll view.
2) for each item to be added (3 textview 2 spinner), add a layout and provide layout params for it i.e width/height/orientation/background etc.
3)add this layout to the scrollview you created in xml by 
findViewById(R.id.scrollviewId).add(layout)
4)create your textviews/spinners in and give them layout params.{ this process is much logical in a pattern of your design so must be very careful}
5)add all these textviews/spinners in the layout you created in step 3.
```

Note: according to your design requirements you might need to add other layouts in between the layout created in step 2/3 and other items created in step 4.

Here is the code you liked:

```
LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_in_xml);
for(int i = 0; i < required_fields.length; i++){

LinearLayout lr = new RelativeLayout(DisplaySadip.this);
    LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lr.serLayoutParams(layoutParams);
lr.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
//add linear layout to your layout in xml
myLayout.add(lr);
//add textview, spinner to this layout now
TextView tv1 = new TextView(YourActivity.this)
tv1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
tv1.setText("......"+i);
lr1.add(tv1)

Spinner spinner1 = new Spinner(YourActivity.this)
spinner.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

Spinner spinner2 = new Spinner(YourActivity.this)
spinner.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

lr.add(spinner1);
lr.add(spinner2);
TextView tv2 = new TextView(YourActivity.this)
    tv2.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    tv2.setText("......"+i);
    lr.add(tv2)
TextView tv3 = new TextView(YourActivity.this)
    tv3.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    tv3.setText("......"+i);
    lr1.add(tv3)
}
```

it shall add add many no of views you want in your layout.

Comment: still new to java so any help is appreciated

Comment: Post the required layout image

Comment: the xml file is the expected layout for each row. the app will have maximum  8 rows.